# como garantir a ordem de leitura das mensagens no Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Tenho um banco de dados relacional e estou migrando pra noSQL , estou usando o kafka para fazer essa migração , existem coleções que precisam que outras já estejam populadas , é possivel garantir a ordem das mensagens? vi algo sobre key , isso realmente ajuda ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível garantir a ordem das mensagens?

Sim, porém, no Kafka, a ordem só pode ser garantida dentro de uma partição. Isso significa que, se as mensagens foram enviadas do produtor em uma ordem específica, o broker as gravará em uma partição e todos os consumidores a lerão na mesma ordem.

E se seu tópico tem mais de uma partição?

Bom, aí entra a questão de definir uma chave. Você pode criar um `ProducerRecord`, especificar uma chave de mensagem. O particionador padrão usará o hash da chave para garantir que todas as mensagens para a mesma chave vão para o mesmo produtor. Esta é a abordagem mais fácil e comum.

Comment: sobre os topicos , sabes dizer se pelo kafka , posso "desligar" um topico por algum tempo ?

sua respsota me ajudou bastante !! obg

Comment: Você quis dizer a partição? Se é isso, não. Tem uma pergunta/resposta sobre isso aqui no [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45499379/18485660).